# Creating an executable encapsulating 2 other projects

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, executable

I'm working on Windows in Eclipse C++. I have this structure in my project:

```
subProject A
   -> creates a static library (works fine)
subProject B encapsulating subproject A
   -> creates a static library (works fine)
subProject TestA
   -> creates an executable (works fine)
subProject TestB
    |dev
      |src
      | CmakeList.txt
    |CmakeList.txt
   -> creates an executable (doesn't work)
```

This is the **CmakeList.txt** in the dev directory for the TestB executable:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS
    $(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

include_directories(${${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADER_FILES FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
  ./*.hpp
  ./*.h)

file(GLOB_RECURSE ${PROJECT_NAME}_SORUCE_FILES FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
  ./*.cpp
  ./*.c)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_FILES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADER_FILES}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_FILES})

# Additional includes and link directories and dependencies
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/A/include)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/B/include)

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES}
                     A
                     B
                     pthread)
elseif(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES}
                     A
                     B
                     pthread)
endif()

# Add a library to the project
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/A/lib)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/B/lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES})

install(FILES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADER_FILES}
     DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/
     PERSMISSIONS OWNER_READ GROUP_READ WORLD_READ)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
     ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
     LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
     RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

In my B subproject, in a file, I have this:

```
#include "A.hpp"

...
A algo;
A.method(parameters)
```

When I build my TestB, I have this weird error appearing in the *B project* on the 2 lines above which makes my build fail:

```
undefined reference to A::A()
undefined reference to A::method(parameter)
```

When I comment these lines and rebuild the *B project* and the *TestB project* it works fine, I have a library in the B project and a .exe in the TestB.

I don't understand where is my problem.

Comment: If you use `A`, you need to link against the static library that project A produces.

Comment: I didn't quite understand where to link it and how. In my CmakeList.txt? Isn't the `link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../install/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/A/lib)` command already linking it?

Comment: No idea, is that where the static library is built and located? I also suggest you try to turn the two `link_directories` commands into one. That's what the [cmake documentation does](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html). It may be that the second call is throwing away the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B` depends on `A`, so add the dependency in `B`'s CMakeLists.txt to A with `target_link_libraries`. Even if it's a static library and there won't be any actual linking when you build `B`, this will anyway give a hint to CMake that every time you link `B` to an executable, you have also have to link *afterwards* to `A`. `A` has to come after `B` in the link command line, so that the symbols needed by `B` are known when you get to link to `A`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) for more details.

If you are looking for a quick fix instead, just change:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES}
                     A
                     B
                     pthread)
```

to this

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXTRA_LIBRARIES}
                     B
                     A
                     pthread)
```